# Cocoa class to reference many entries by a single key

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, data-structures, mapping

I need a Cocoa data structure to keep something like a list of locations of a set of insects in a field over time. Clearly an `NSDictionary` has to have unique keys, so I couldn't use the insect as a key and `MKUserlocation` as the object.

Is there any other class besides `NSArray` where one does not have to step through, `if`/`else`-ing at each index?

There seems to be such a thing as `NSList` discussed in various places but nothing in the Apple docs.

I also saw a reference to `NSIndexSet` one uses in conjunction to an `NSArray`, but again reading the Apple docs suggests it's not useful to me.

Comment: An NSDictionary of NSArrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each insect have a key in an `NSMutableDictionary`. Make each key's object an `NSMutableArray` of locations.

Answer (score 4):

Since Cocoa framework does not offer a multimap container, you could implement your own by creating an `NSMutableDictionary`, and populating it with `NSMutableArray` objects.

```
NSMutableDictionary locByInsect = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

// Adding a location for an insect:

MyInsect *insect = ... // Don't forget to provide hash code and equality checks
MyLocation *location = ...
NSMutableDictionary *insectLocations = locByInsect[insect];
if (insectLocations == nil) {
    insectLocations = [NSMutableArray array];
    locByInsect[insect] = insectLocations;
}
[insectLocations addObject:location];

// Retrieving all locations for an insect
for (MyLocation *loc in locByInsect[insect]) {
    NSLog(@"Saw %@ at %@", insect, loc);
}
```

Comment: I knew I had to settle for a combination of the two, but whether a Dictionary of Arrays or an Array of Dictionaries, I couldn't decide. There's a third dimension to it which is The history of field monitoring, latest, recent and oldest bug movements, but the dict would hold an array composed of 3 mini arrays. What you've done seems easiest to accommodate